# javascript compatibility

Tags: javascript, web, usability, user-experience

I remember that few years ago it was mandatory that when we design a website that uses JavaScript, we should think about those users who doesn't have JavaScript enabled, and should make that website in a way which without JavaScript it should be working fine,
but nowadays websites are using JavaScript heavily ! so is that theory still should be followed ?

Comment: Just check the sites you visit every day without javascript and answer to your question yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The theory we should follow is: force user to upgrade/switch-to the browser that supports javascript (a modern browser).

5-6 years ago the concept was different as IE6 made our life too hard and we had to make websites compatible without javascript.

Internet Explorer was too hackable with javascript so people started to disable javascript just for security purposes (unwanted neverending popups, unwanted trojans that were installed without our knowledge).

I'm not saying a website should not work without javascript, but today's browsers don't have a javascript turn off switch.

And as a side note, if you switch Javascript off, 98% of sites won't work. Thats just because programmers today don't know about what life we had with IE family.

Comment: Also, in the olden days, JS sites weren't accessible by Googlebot, that seems to be OK these days, so it's less of a concern for that as well.